# Sorting Outlook calendar All Appointments view by next appointment date

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, sorting

I like the All Appointments view in the Outlook [2007] calendar, but I can't figure out how to get it sorted by the next appointment date. Put another way, I'd like to see the nearest-in-time appointments at the top, and the most distant ones at the bottom. This is the order I see them in on the To-Do list.

My instinct was to sort by Start Date, but that doesn't work for recurring appointments - their Start Date doesn't change, although the date for the next occurrence does.

Am I missing something obvious, or is the value not available for sorting? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After examining every field available in the "Field Chooser", your conclusion is correct - the value representing the next date of a recurring event is not available.  The next date can be calculated if you write a program that interoperates with Outlook, but that would be a substantial project.  Bummer!